# While you save a file in .csv,how to remove the hyphen in the file name

Tags: java

When you save a file name say "01-01-2012.csv". How can the hyphens between the given file name be removed automatically using a java code. After executing the code I need the file name to appear as "01012012.csv".

And i need the code for accepting N number of inputs.

```
"01-01-2012.csv" ---after executing the code --- "01012012.csv"
"02-01-2012.csv" ---after executing the code --- "02012012.csv"
```

And likewise so on for N number of inputs.

Comment: `"01-01-2012".replaceAll("-","");`?

Comment: Why don't make the name correct before saving? Also you can rename file after saving: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Comment: If you're these filenames represent dates, it's better practice to save them in yyyymmdd format.

Answer (score 3):

```
"01-01-2012.csv".replaceAll("-", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> convertFnames(List<String> fnames) {
  final List<String> newStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (String s : fnames) newStrings.add(s.replaceAll("-", "");
  return newStrings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String hyphenString = "a-string-that-contains-hyphens";

 String noHyphenString = hyphenString.replaceAll("-", "");
```